# Sequence of execution of methods in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to find out the Right sequence of the method execution in the jquery.

here is the sample script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(){
        $("div").fadeOut(function(){
            console.log("i am no 1");
        }).fadeIn(function(){
            console.log("i am no 2");
        }).show('slow',function(){
            console.log('i am no 3');
        });
    });
});
```

So, when i click the button with id="start". then the o/p in the console should be

> i am no 1
>
> i am no 2
>
> i am no 3

but the actual o/p is

> i am no 1
>
> i am no 3
>
> i am no 2

so, i want to know how to know how to decide the sequence of execution of the method in jquery script? what is the basis of priority ???

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only reproduce this problem in [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tgraD/) when using jQuery versions older than 1.6.4.  If you use 1.6.4 or newer, the jsFiddle works in all browsers I've tried.

My guess is that you're either trying to use a capability that wasn't implemented until 1.6 or you're running into a buggy behavior that wasn't fixed until 1.6.

You can see the working order here with jQuery 1.8.0: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tgraD/

You can see the failed order here with jQuery 1.5.2: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/SJns7/

Comment: Thanks man, you are right. its giving desired o/p in jsFiddle with new version on jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

In short:

When you call `fadeOut` the function you pass into it gets called **after** the effect completes, and **then** the effect caused by `fadeIn` is processed.

I believe you should read up on general Javascript programming (callbacks, asynchronous function calls etc.)

Comment: This is entirely an issue with asynchronous callbacks. Good call.

Comment: The OP is looking for three consecutive async callbacks that should get called in proper sequence because the operations should be ordered by jQuery's animation queue.  I don't think the OP is misunderstanding what you are writing about.

Comment: When he says: `the o/p in the console **should** be` - that's when he misunderstands. there is nothing in the code suggesting what the output SHOULD be.

Comment: @wroniasty: you point out that i misunderstood regarding console. am i missing something here? your suggestions are welcome. thanks for your time.

Comment: what I meant was, that you expected the callback functions to be called in a certain order, which was a wrong assumption. The `fadeIn` `fadeOut` and `show` functions are called in the order you specified, but the callbacks you passed into them don't have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jfriend00.
i tried the same code in the jsFiddle and on the localhost and i got the expected o/p evertime.

The incorrect o/p came from the W3schools.com try section. i tried the code there and i got the wrong o/p and confused myself. so,i learned a lesson that jsFiddle is much better than 
w3schools try your self.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the function executes before completing the executing of first function. To overcome this call the second function in success callback of the first and the third function in the success callback of the second.

Comment: jQuery has an animation queue that will queue and order the animations for you - your suggestion is not required.